# npm autoprefixer are not working in my front-end markup project

Tags: npm, cross-browser, web-frontend, autoprefixer

I am trying to use autoprefixer in my front end project but it's not working as expected.

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "sass scss/app.scss styles/app.css -w",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' styles/app.css -o styles/app.min.css",
    "build": "sass scss/app.scss styles/app.min.css --style=compressed"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.52.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on interent.
[Source code of this solution](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/autoprefixer-in-npm-script-not-working-important/231960/7?u=iamtheasad)

Replace these line of code in JSON:

```
"browserslist": ["last 10 versions"],
"prefix:css": "postcss styles/app.css --use=autoprefixer --map=false --output=styles/app.prefix.css",
```

Details:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "browserslist": ["last 10 versions"],
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "sass scss/app.scss styles/app.css -w",
    "prefix:css": "postcss styles/app.css --use=autoprefixer --map=false --output=styles/app.prefix.css",
    "build": "sass scss/app.scss styles/app.min.css --style=compressed"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.52.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.0.0"
  }
}
```